# How do I get all the <li> elements from within a div using Watin?

Tags: c#, html, watin

I have never used Watin before today. I need to get a collection of 'li' elements that are within a 'div'

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I only want the li elements within the div id='myDiv'..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it..

```
var liList = _browser.Div("myDiv").ElementsWithTag("li");
```